# Using pure javascript (no JQuery/3rd-party libraries), how to concatenate collections from document.getElementsByTagName to iterate in single loop

Tags: javascript, concatenation, getelementsbytagname

What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");

var concatenated = textareas.concat(inputs).concat(selects);

for(var i = 0; i < concatenated.length; i++) {
   //Do something on each concatenated[i] item
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using 1 queryselector

```
<textarea value= "The DOM is very useful." />
<input class="intro" value='This example demonstrates the method' />

<script>
var z = document.querySelectorAll("input, textarea");

//now z has input and textarea

for(i=0;i<z.length;i++)
{ 

    alert( z[i]);
}
</script>
```

Comment: This method is most elegant presented thus far, and, when performed repeatedly, seems to operate faster than the spread and Array.prototype syntax (at least in Firefox 58.0.2 64-bit).  I'm glad to have been informed of the other syntaxes presented, though I will actually use your solution in my application.  Since I'm new here, I'm not sure about the etiquette of changing accepted answers.  Other answers thus far most technically answer the question as asked (I should have asked it differently -- I didn't know about querySelectorAll).

Comment: Clicking on the Tick inFront on my answer will change it to accepted answer. If this is the one you accepted

Comment: I know how to change the accepted answer.  However, since I'm new here I'm not sure if it's against the rules (I'm looking into that now).

Comment: Going by the etiquette/rules/practices presented here [ https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93969/is-changing-the-accepted-answer-frowned-upon ], I am changing my accepted answer as I find your solution to be the most elegant and most helpful, and it seems to perform better.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ES6:

```
const concatenated = [...textareas, ...inputs, ...selects];
```

Comment: Works beautifully, and thanks for your lightning-fast response (< 2 minutes after I posted).  I'm fairly new to this.  How do I accept your answer and give you a bazillion points?

Comment: @JohnDoe: You can only accept an answer 15 minutes after you ask the question.   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

From ES6 onwards, you can simply [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) them into another array:

```
var concatenated = [...textareas, ...inputs, ...selects];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype` to make use of `Array` methods on array-like objects. In this case, you can create a small helper function to call `slice` on your collections, turning them into arrays:

```
function toArray(collection){ return Array.prototype.slice.call(collection, 0) }
```

So your queries get structured like this instead:

```
var textareas = toArray(document.getElementsByTagName("textarea"));
```

Then, you're free to use `concat` to join them.

Even better, you can use `document.querySelectorAll` to just get them all in the first place, then loop over them:

```
var concatenated = document.querySelectorAll('textarea, input, select')
```

Comment: For what I'm currently attempting, I think that the spread syntax brought to my attention by SLaks and clarified by lonesomeday is most appropriate.  However, I can see a myriad of future uses for your method in other things, so thanks much for this!

Comment: @JohnDoe Glad to help. Getting to know javascript for real outside of libraries is always a good idea. This site is a bit dated, but still helpful as you explore vanilla JS http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/